# Options for migrating anonymous InfoPath 2010 form to SP 2016? Nintex? Aspx? JavaScript page?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, architecture, nintex, anonymous-access

I've been thrust into an architect role on SharePoint and have zero knowledge on how to best do this migration.

We have old SP 2010 InfoPath forms that need to be rebuilt (since InfoPath is no longer supported). The form gets reference data from SharePoint 2010 lists anonymously.

The form is public facing and read only - no data is submitted; only read and calculated. Basically, people select options from a few dropdowns, and then there's simple calculations that are displayed on the form once this is done.

We need to come up with approaches for migrating/rebuilding the form and its functionality.

1. Nintex forms? I'm not sure if it's possible to embed a Nintex form within a SP page with anonymous access? We can't/don't want to use a Workflow as this is a suggested work around from posts I've read. The form is read only, so there's no point in having a workflow.
2. Nintex live? That was another suggestion. Am not sure how feasible it is, or if Nintex live allows custom JavaScript?
3. Some sort of aspx page? I have no idea how to do this as I've never created one for SP, but exploring all options here, is it possible to have an aspx page, with C# in the code behind to access the lists anonymously?
4. Knockout JavaScript application? If JavaScript can make rest api calls (or whatever) anonymously to the SharePoint reference lists?
5. PowerApps/Power Platform application embedded (if possible) within a SharePoint page?
6. Any other options?

Note: Nintex option is no extra cost as we already have Nintex licenses.
Any help/suggestions would be appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2016, 2019 are both supporting InfoPath. The most stable approach is migrate existing forms to SP2013, then migrate to SP2016 (your platform). However, Microsoft said they are not going to support in next version.

Regarding all the approaches you listed above are **not migration** option. They are alternatives. You can **re-build** your InfoPath with those alternatives according to old logic and similar UI.

Giving that your forms are readonly and you're on-premise, I will not consider Nintex and cloud service like PowerApps. Because it required additional license budget. Those tools are great but too powerful for your requirement.

Build your own Spfx page with Knockout sounds best approach because it is license-free and compatible with future SharePoint products (including SP Online).

Comment: Thank you for your distinction on migrating vs rebuilding. I've updated the question to include that and also we have Nintex licenses, so no extra costs there. In regards to your suggestion, can JavaScript perform rest api calls anonymously?

Comment: If you setup anonymous on your sharepoint site, then JS should be able to call its API. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/manage-anonymous-access-for-a-web-application